# Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET 5 web project - Autogenerate LINQ filters query

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, entity-framework-core

I have .NET 5 MVC project (original ASP.NET 3.1 Core MVC), where I use EF Core 5 + React + Redux and MSSql.

I looking for a find way, how to send via REST GET request, data from React form (the form with, select, input, range boxes) into the backend and autogenerate WHERE SQL query from the sand filters, with selected values.

Is there any EF Core feature or I must generate this query for example in FOREACH like:

```
query = ...
foreach param_filter in
   query = query.Where(...)
```

I have an HTML form with filters and their values are generated from DB, and each website page has another count and types of filters, but each filter has a unique string ID

**ADD INFO:**

Input request:

```
{
    "name": "Application",
    "values": [
        {
            "name": "Smart Homes & Cities | Industrial | Automotive | Security | Consumer",
            "value": "Smart Homes & Cities | Industrial | Automotive | Security | Consumer"
        }
    ],
    "type": "select",
    "field": "ant_application",
    "sort": 4
}
```

I would like to get REST API request with filters array, and for each field type, generate something like:

```
foreach (var f in filters)
    query.Where(p => p.Field == p.field).AndValueNotIn(f.values);
```

Where p means products list, where each product has its own field values

Now I use in EF Core DB procedure call like:

```
.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC GetGroupFilters {groupId}").AsEnumerable()
```

MSSql procedure has the only SQL (join, select, union), and returns formatted rows from DB which I load into Object and use LINQ, I have 2 choices:

1. generate raw text from filters with **SQL WHERE** and send it into the procedure
2. generate **LINQ .Where()** etc in backend side with C#

I think then choice number 1 will be faster and better, but still, find the best solution

Is there any better solution?

Comment: I recommend to look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: this is only a reference to the same solution I described above, moreover, it is useless when the table column name is stored in the DB and the rows will be many, and with each request different

Comment: This is really broad. Provides and specifications for the types and meanings of inputs.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I add more info to the original question.

Comment: You can simply chain `Where`s: `query.Where(...).Where(...).Where(...)`. There are many questions on how to compose filter queries at runtime.

Comment: @GertArnold I am looking for the "best" solution and also find a way how to do it. I update my question, where I describe two ways how I think then to do it, but the question is if anybody knows a better solution or tool(library or Nuget package) how to do it. Yes chain LINQ query is my original idea, which I describe above (but a simple way in foreach)

Comment: Chaining `Where` statements is what you want. It's simple. You can build the predicates using a predicate builder. This is all stuff that has been covered many times before.

Comment: Actually nothing special here to generate LINQ query dynamically. But use case still not clear. Probably better description for JSON properties are needed.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I have done such a thing

I Recommend You to Learn about **Expression Trees** in **Linq.Expression** as The Link Below I Implement this Before You can Find Your Questions Answers in this [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries)

but for More Understading How can Implement This I Put Some **Example** Codes Below:

```
     // Comment   _Queryable.Where(x=>x.Something) | This Queryable from 
     // Type Of Generics (Where Any model With Any Field With This)
     var query = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(keyParameter, filter.Key),
                        Expression.Constant(filter.Value));
                    MethodCallExpression whereExpression = Expression.Call(
                        typeof(Queryable),
                        "Where",
                        new Type[] {_queryable.ElementType},
                        _queryable.Expression,
                        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(query, new 
                      ParameterExpression[] {keyParameter}));
                    _queryable = 
          _queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T(whereExpression);
```

Sorry For My Bad English **I Wish Its Help You**

Comment: This sample code is not exactly what you want but it has the concepts you want.